# Get storyboard ID programmatically

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

How can I get storyboard ID programmatically (opened storyboard)? I want to get storyboard ID and than call different code for every storyboard. Something like if ID == myStoryboard then...

Comment: Hi, you have your code open on your screen, and you have the idea of what you're trying to do inside your head... but we don't. We have no idea. So your question only makes sense in the context of that information... it makes no sense to us without it... so can you please tell us all the relevant information so that we know what you're talking about? Please read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and follow it? thanks :)

Comment: I set ID for all my storyboards, and when user opens storyboard number 5 with ID "5th_storyboard" how can I save that "5th_storyboard" (storyboard ID) to NSString *stroyboard_id?

Comment: Please read that article... then update your question to match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it with `NSString *restorationId = self.restorationIdentifier;`

Comment: When i write this code i get (null) what i am doing wrong?